# ASP.NET webapplication deployment - with domain / server name access

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dns, windows-server-2008

I have deployed my ASP.NET web application on IIS (windows 2008 server). I have created a virtual directory (named **TestApp**) and all the users on local area network are accessing it with the following URL.

http://"SERVERNAME"/TestApp/Default.aspx

My client wants that, it should be accessed as following URL

http://"SERVERNAME"/Default.aspx

There is single application deployed on the server.

Could you let me know how can i implement this thing??

Comment: why this question get downgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a `virtual directory` on the existing site, you need to add a **new** `web site`

[Create a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: i tried to add new website instead of virtual directly, but now when i am browsing the site from IIS its opening localhost page instead of website default page.

Comment: @yadavr: http://YOURSERVERNAME/ will ping the default site. If all what you're doing is testing locally, decide any domain that looks good for you and add the binding / entry on hosts files. Check this other question that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235701/iis-can-i-create-a-host-header-for-an-intranet-site

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's fairly simple.

1. Remove your current app, including all files and settings in IIS (i.e.: delete everything).
2. Run the deploy wizard again, BUT be carefull of the path that it's given to your application: by default, you should see "http://SERVERNAME/TestApp/". Remove "TestApp". The wizard will show you a warning message, just continue.
3. Finish the wizard as usual, and voila!

I did this 2 or 3 times yet.

Comment: i am working on server there is no method for deploying the application , i can just upload the already published application in Inetpub->wwwroot

Comment: Install the web deploy extension, it's make deployment so simple. [http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy)